# their wrath or their wraths?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, uncountable-nouns, countability

When talking about a group of people, e.g. project managers, which of these is more correct:

> Project managers are generally goodhearted, but here's a list of things you should avoid doing lest you invoke their wrath:

or

> Project managers are generally goodhearted, but here's a list of things you should avoid doing lest you invoke their wraths:

Comment: **Wrath** is a singular noun.

Comment: @WeatherVane so wrath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: `wrath` is correct.

Long term lesson:

Wrath is an [uncountable noun](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/countable-nouns), so we only use its singular form.

You can find the solution to this type of problem by looking the word up in your favorite dictionary and looking for the term `uncountable` or `noncount`. For instance, check out the word's definition at the [Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/wrath).

The opposite of an `uncountable noun` is a `countable noun`, which means that we use its pluralized form as usual.